# Flex 4 custom TextInput skin -> new graphical element is darkened for some reason?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, skinning, spark-skinning

Flex 4 / AS3: I made a custom skin for TextInput by selecting New->MXML Skin and choosing 'TextInput - spark.components' as the Host Component. Therefore my starting point was the 'default skin class for Spark TextInput component'.

Within the new skin (called 'textinput_skin') I added a new visual element that I want to appear to the left of the text in the Text Input.

The 'button shape' should look pretty much exactly like this: http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning/_jcr_content/articlecontentAdobe/image_2.adimg.mw.125.jpg/1279877300467.jpg
(because I copied the code for drawing it from an Adobe example).

Instead inside my TextInput it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/8aWE7HB.png

This is my code in the custom TextInput skin (most is now new, but I added the new visual element):

```
<!-- border - NOT NEW STUFF --> 
<!--- @private -->
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="border">
    <s:stroke>     
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>

<!-- fill - NOT NEW STUFF -->
<!--- Defines the appearance of the TextInput component's background. -->
<s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
    <s:fill>
        <!--- @private Defines the background fill color. -->
        <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<!-- shadow - NOT NEW STUFF -->
<!--- @private -->
<s:Rect left="1" top="1" right="1" height="1" id="shadow">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="0.12" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Group> <!-- NEW PART: group with horizontal layout, to get graphical element to the left of the text in the text input -->
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Group> <!-- a second group that defines the 'image' shape and interior text (looks like a green rect with rounded corners and text inside)'
        <!-- border and fill -->
        <s:Rect id="rect" radiusX="4" radiusY="4" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" left="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0x77CC22"/>
            </s:fill>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x131313" weight="2"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- highlight on top -->
        <s:Rect radiusX="4" radiusY="4" top="2" right="2" left="2" height="50%">
            <s:fill>
                <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha=".5"/>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha=".1"/>
                </s:LinearGradient>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- text -->
        <s:Label text="txt" color="0xFFFFFF" 
                 textAlign="center"
                 verticalAlign="middle"
                 horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
                 left="6" right="6" top="6" bottom="6" 
                 />
    </s:Group>

    <!-- text - NOT NEW STUFF - the normal textDisplay element for the Text Input -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableTextBase#textDisplay -->
    <s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay"
                        verticalAlign="middle"
                        widthInChars="10"
                        left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" />
</s:Group>

<!--- Defines the Label that is used for prompt text. The includeInLayout property is false so the prompt text does not affect measurement. -->
<s:Label id="promptDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
            verticalAlign="middle"
            mouseEnabled="false" mouseChildren="false"
            includeIn="normalWithPrompt,disabledWithPrompt" 
            includeInLayout="false"
            />
```

And I use the skin, like so:

```
<s:TextInput skinClass="model.textinput_skin" fontFamily="Arial" id="textinputid" name="item3" visible="true" editable="true" />
```

The problem is that the graphical element is *dimmed*. It looks like it might have an alpha < 1, or has another transparent item in front of it. As you can see in the code I made my text color 0xFFFFFF, yet it clearly displays as darker than white.

Can anyone help me determine what is *darkening* my element?

By the way, I'm aware there is the 'shadow' element. But in updateDisplayList() shadow is set visible only if borderVisible == true. I tried setting borderVisible = false, and I tried completely removing the shadow element from the skin. It doesn't seem to be the problem.

Also, at one point I was using an image instead of drawing the shape programatically. Even the image was darkened.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the prompt displaying above your new graphical element?  That would dim it.

Comment: Also, to enable your trouble shooting, start by commenting out the various parts of that skin. Adobe's skins have a lot of graphical elements in them. Don't comment out the required skin part(s) (the RichEditableText with id="textDisplay"). That might help you understand what each element is and where your mysterious stuff is coming from.

Comment: I don't think there is a prompt. (I believe by Prompt you mean text like "Enter text here").

Comment: And I have tried removing more graphical elements from the skin but it results in crashes because the component expects the parts to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.

Elsewhere in the skin was this block of code:

```
<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.core.FlexVersion;

    private var paddingChanged:Boolean;

    /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. */
    static private const exclusions:Array = ["background", "textDisplay", "promptDisplay", "border"];

    /* exclusions before Flex 4.5 for backwards-compatibility purposes */
    static private const exclusions_4_0:Array = ["background", "textDisplay", "promptDisplay"];
... etc.
```

I needed to add my new element to the exclusions array, to make it one of "the skin elements that should not be colorized". I have no idea why but this fixed it.

New code:

```
<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.core.FlexVersion;

    private var paddingChanged:Boolean;

    /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. */
    static private const exclusions:Array = ["text_img", "background", "textDisplay", "promptDisplay", "border"];

    /* exclusions before Flex 4.5 for backwards-compatibility purposes */
    static private const exclusions_4_0:Array = ["text_img", "background", "textDisplay", "promptDisplay"];
```

Where text_img is the id of my group that draws the graphical element.